# JSP how to change application name

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat6

I have a JSP java application that has a name `AAA-master` so currently my application is accessible via `http://localhost:8080/AAA-master/`

The project is allso called `AAA-master` ... is there a way to make my application be accessible via `http://localhost:8080/AAA/`?

I searched everywhere and my google skills have failed me :(

i use tomcat6 with this project but i am migrating to tomcat7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your `server.xml` under `Tomcat\conf`

```
 <Context path="/AAA" docBase="yourWarFilelocation" debug="0" reloadable="true">
```

`docBase` is the location of your war file or Application root directory path

e.g. `C:\\Amit\\developments\\abc`

Comment: This did the job, thank you ! but is there not a better way to achieve this with configuration in the application inself?

Comment: another way is you can put this thing in context.xml under META-INF in your application only.